# Why couldn't Bifröst Bridge be constructed again?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, thor-2011

In the *Thor* movie, when Thor started to destroy Bifröst Bridge, Loki said Thor not to do this because he (Thor) would never be able to meet with her (Jane) again. And, when Bifröst bridge was finally destroyed, it was shown like its permanent damage.

Assuming they were gods with enormous technology, why couldn't Bifröst Bridge be constructed again? Was that particular technology lost or something similar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Likely it *can* be reconstructed, but will probably take quite a while; just consider how long it takes to (re)build a conventional long span suspension bridge or bridge-tunnel.
More probable is that in the heat of the moment Loki simply didn't fully state the situation, instead opting to try and emotionalize Thor into not destroying the bridge by making him think he would never see Jane again. If instead Loki had said "Destroy the bridge and you wont see her again for X time" then it would become a more rational decision, and Thor would able to accept it more easily.

Its also possible that X time would be longer than lifespan of Jane.

Comment: That explains why Loki said that... But, why does Movie show it like permanent damage?

Comment: Better for the sequel. It is more entertaining for Thor to have tried 100 different (failed) ways to get back to Earth, and to make the movie about his epic return, rather than for him to have sat on his butt for X time waiting for it to be rebuilt.

Comment: Also: even though they can rebuild it (they have the technology!), that doesn't necessarily mean they can do so before Jane dies of old age.

Comment: @SachinShekhar also, there is no indication of how much time passed between when Thor destroyed the bridge and then he is later standing on it, asking the guardian if he can see Jane. It could have been the next day for all we know, so gauging how much re-construction could/should have been shown is difficult.

Comment: @Tacroy You have point..

Comment: And, I have added that point to answer.

Comment: Also... consider the Cube (from Captain America / Avengers).  We know it's Asgardian tech, related to world-travelling.  Maybe the Asgardians *can't* build the bridge without it.

Comment: For what it's worth, since this answer was posted it's been confirmed that the Bifrost WAS rebuilt (by the time of *The Dark World*), but that it took a while (hence Thor needing other means of getting to Midgard for *The Avengers*).